# Unable to connect to EC2 instance using JCONSOLE

Tags: tomcat, ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys, jconsole

I am using JCONSOLE to monitor memory utilization of EC2 instance w.r.to JVM, I want to set it for tomcat, Mean I want to monitor Tomcat.

I have gone through many links, like 
1): http://gabenell.blogspot.in/2010/04/connecting-to-jmx-on-tomcat-6-through.html

I followed the steps mentioned in 2nd URL
Still I am unable to connect to EC2 instance using JCONSOLE and my jconsole says that
"Connection Failed: Retry?"

I am worried about how to import "openssh-key" I think I am lacking in this point

1st URL says at some point

start ssh tunnel with:

```
ssh user@aws-host -L10001:127.0.0.1:10001 -L10002:127.0.0.1:10002
```

I am unable to do this step, Will you please elaborate more on this topic.

I made setting in security group of Amazone also [You can see amazon security group setting in this immage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwJlq.png)

Comment: 1st link is : http://www.cod.ro/2012/08/monitoring-tomcat-7-on-rhel-aws-using.html

Comment: 2nd link is: http://gabenell.blogspot.in/2010/04/connecting-to-jmx-on-tomcat-6-through.html

Comment: Why are you unable to start the SSH tunnel, and what needs to be elaborated?